# How to remove Price filter section from layered navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

Iam trying hard but still not getting to remove SHOP BY and PRICE FILTER SECTIONS from layered navigation please help me in removing those items.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for Downvote actually this is basic question..!!

for removing Price filter Goto `Catalog->manage attributes` find price attribute and select `no` in the option `Use In Layered Navigation`.

for removing SHOP BY goto `app/design/frontend/your_theme/default/template/catalog/navigation` and in `left.phtml` file find this code

```
<div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Browse By') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
```

and then put `echo` in comments.
Hope it works.

Comment: Price filter removed but shop by still exists.

Comment: Clear the cache and reindex data

Comment: done both no use still.

Comment: may be you have custom theme.

Comment: then do a this:P add `display:none;` rule for `css` class `block-title`

Comment: I use `RWD` theme

Comment: lol display:none; worked anyway I feel this is not the right approach.

Comment: under rwd package which all theme u r having

Comment: @PradeepSanku didn't get you

Comment: price filer you can remove in admin->attributes-manage attributer, then foud price and found Used for Sorting in Product Listing and then switch to No and save attribute

Answer (score 2):

create own module and use next snippets

code for your config.xml:

```
......
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <core_collection_abstract_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <my_module_remove_price>
                        <class>MyModule/observer</class>
                        <method>hidePriceFromLayeredNav</method>
                    </my_module_remove_price>
                </observers>            
            </core_collection_abstract_load_before>
        <events>
.......
```

Code for your observer:

```
public function hidePriceFromLayeredNav($event) {
    $collection = $event->getEvent()->getCollection();
    if($collection instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Attribute_Collection){            
        $txt=$collection->getSelect()->__toString();
        if(strpos($txt,'additional_table.is_filterable')){
            $collection->removePriceFilter();
        }           
    }
}
```

PS: using this logic you can hide prices for some customer groups or using config settings